# Multiple actions after a condition in a JavaScript ternary operation

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I'm trying to create a ternary expression than when is true, i'll assign several new keys to an object.
This returns an error:

```
const entity = {};

    element.data.icon ? 
    entity['url'] = element.data.icon.data.image[0].url 
    entity['alt'] = element.data.icon.data.image[0].alt
    entity['title'] = element.data.icon.data.image[0].title :
    entity['url'] = ''
```

I'm trying to get the equivalent to this:

```
const entity = {};
if (element.data.icon) {
        entity['url'] = element.data.icon.data.image[0].url 
        entity['alt'] = element.data.icon.data.image[0].alt
        entity['title'] = element.data.icon.data.image[0].title 
    }
    entity['url'] = ''
```

How should I do it? if possible

Comment: Since you have four assignments following the check, I would advise to stick with the more readable `if-else` structure. The ternary operator will simply make this hard to debug and honestly. will not add any performance boost to your code.

Comment: Did you forget an `else` in the last code block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use the `if` version? It would be more readable.

Having said that, you can use commas like so:

```js
element.data.icon
  ? (entity['url'] = element.data.icon.data.image[0].url,
     entity['alt'] = element.data.icon.data.image[0].alt,
     entity['title'] = element.data.icon.data.image[0].title)
  : entity['url'] = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary to assign different complete objects:

```
const entity = element.data.icon 
    ? {
        url: element.data.icon.data.image[0].url, 
        alt: element.data.icon.data.image[0].alt,
        title: element.data.icon.data.image[0].title
    } 
    : { 
        url: ""
    };
```